# iOS splash-screen status bar background color change to blue and text black

Tags: ios, react-native, colors, splash-screen, statusbar

I have implemented a splash screen in native iOS for my react-native code, I need to set the status bar color of the splash screen to blue and the font color of the status bar to black, let me know if anyone has any idea about how to achieve this.

It is also okay if the solution is for the whole app.

[image]

Comment: Please add more info: How did you change splash screen?

Answer (score 0):

1. use safe area view
2. <StatusBar
   backgroundColor={'blue'}
   barStyle={'dark-content'}
   />
3. if you want this type in whole app then pass the same code in app.js file within navigation container or main view.

Comment: I need to set in splash screen which is implemented in native iOS, and by the way above will not work in iOS, it is only for Android.